# Heartbeat with no utilization nor load with ganglia

Tags: monitoring, ganglia

I use [ganglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglia_(software)) to monitor my computer cluster. On Ganglia Web Interface, I sometimes have the following issue: given a node, according to the physical view and the node view, the node has sent a heartbeat recently, but there is not load no CPU utilization:

[image]

What could explain this?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.